# Javascript synchronous request to icCube

Tags: javascript, iccube, iccube-reporting

I need to combine the results of 3 MDX requests named mdx1, mdx2 and mdx3 before displaying them.

How do I wait for the 3 processes to complete before calling the display method?

Is it possible to call the executeRequest method synchronously?

Here is the code structure:

```
executeRequest(new viz.MdxGviRequest(mdx1), {}, function(gviTable) {
// process result1
});
executeRequest(new viz.MdxGviRequest(mdx2), {}, function(gviTable) {
// process result2
});
executeRequest(new viz.MdxGviRequest(mdx3), {}, function(gviTable) {
// process result3
});

// combine result1, result2 and result3 into result
// display result using Google table chart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As icCube is using jQuery here is a possible solution using the when/done feature of jQuery.

```
var res1_done = $.Deferred();
var res2_done = $.Deferred();
var res2_done = $.Deferred();

var res1, res2, res3;

function onAllResultDone() {
   // handle here your results (res1/res2/res3)
}

$.when( res1_done, res2_done, res3_done ).done(function() {
  onAllResultDone();
});

executeRequest(new viz.MdxGviRequest(mdx1), {}, function(gviTable) {
  res1 = ...;
  res1_done.resolve();
});
executeRequest(new viz.MdxGviRequest(mdx2), {}, function(gviTable) {
  res2 = ...;
  res2_done.resolve();
});
executeRequest(new viz.MdxGviRequest(mdx3), {}, function(gviTable) {
  res3 = ...;
  res3_done.resolve();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery, you can use we [`when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and [`done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). So, just put those `executeRequest`'s inside `when` and combine the results in `done`.